# Set node distance between borders in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, block

From

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [->, dashed]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=3.5cm,>=latex']
    \node [block] (A) {A};
    \node [block,right of=A] (B) {B};
    \node [block,right of=B] (C) {loooooooooooooooong C};
    \node [block,right of=C] (D) {D};

    \draw [line] (A) -- (B);
    \draw [line] (B) -- (C);
    \draw [line] (C) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get this figure

[image]

How can I set the distance between the nodes' borders rather than their centers?

In the figure the distance between `B` and `loooooooooooooooong C` is shorter than the distance between `A` and `B`.

Comment: Related: [Difference between “right of=” and “right=of” in PGF/TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9386/difference-between-right-of-and-right-of-in-pgf-tikz)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `right = of` (which is the syntax for `positioning` library) instead of `right of =`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [->, dashed]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=3.5cm,>=latex']
    \node [block] (A) {A};
    \node [block,right = of A] (B) {B};
    \node [block,right = of B] (C) {loooooooooooooooong C};
    \node [block,right = of C] (D) {D};

    \draw [line] (A) -- (B);
    \draw [line] (B) -- (C);
    \draw [line] (C) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't make any difference for me for some reason. Either `right=of` or `right of=` use node centers.

Comment: Ah I found the problem -- the `on grid` option if set for nodes messes this up.