# TikZ: distance between edges of nodes

Tags: tikz-node, tikz-positioning

I want to be able to control the distance between the edges of nodes in TikZ. In the below example, I want the left edge of "Node B" to be exactly 5 cm from the right edge of Node A. However, `right of=A, node distance=5cm` sets the distance between the centres of the nodes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, backgrounds, calc, intersections, decorations.markings, decorations.pathreplacing, positioning, shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw node[draw, rectangle, text centered] (A) {Node A};

\draw node[draw, rectangle, right of=A, node distance=5cm, text centered] (B) {Node B};

\begin{scope}[>=latex]
\draw[<->] ($(A.east)$) -- ($(B.west)$) node[midway, above] {\tiny{I want this distance to be 5 cm}};
\draw[<->] ($(A)+(0mm,-5mm)$) -- ($(B)+(0mm,-5mm)$) node[midway, below] {\tiny{not this distance}};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I found this related answer but the solution (i.e., using "right = of A" instead of "right of = A") doesn't work for me: [Set node distance between borders in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240639/set-node-distance-between-borders-in-tikz)

Comment: Why does it not? Did you load the `positioning` library and set the `node distance` to 5cm **before** you have used `right=of A`? (Or implicitly: `right=5cm of A`.) Usually the node distance is set on an outer scope and not on the node itself.

Comment: I didn't know that the order mattered. I was using `right=of A, node distance=5cm`. It works now. Thanks for also suggesting the short notation, which I didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

Your code example is better to write on the following way:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, 
                backgrounds, 
                calc, 
                decorations.markings, decorations.pathreplacing, 
                intersections, 
                positioning, 
                shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[> = latex,
node distance = 50mm,
                        ]

\draw node[draw]                (A) {Node A};  % default shape is rectangle
\draw node[draw, right=of A]    (B) {Node B};   % used is positioning package sybntay

\draw[<->]  (A) -- node[above, font=\tiny] {I want this distance to be 5 cm} (B);
\draw[<->]  ($(A.south)+(0mm,-5mm)$) 
                -- node[below, font=\tiny] {not this distance}
            ($(B.south)+(0mm,-5mm)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- As @Qrrbrbirlbel mentioned in his comment, `node distance` is better to define outside of nodes. Above is defined as `tikzpicture` option, however you can define it by `\tikzset` before nodes or even globally in document preamble.
- At drawing nodes the  for default shape is assumed `rectangle`.
- If you not prescribe size of the node, its border is drawn around its content consider default value of `inner sep`, so in such cases defining `text=centered` has not sense. BTW, `text=centered` is obsolete syntax (with some rare exceptions), instead it you should use `align=center`.
- For distance between border of nodes you should use `positioning` syntax. In your case `right=of A` (or `right= 5cm od A`, if you not like to use globally defined `node distance).
- For more about `tikz` you need to read its documentation, at list first tutorial in part I and part III: *TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm* (complete documentation is huge (1321 pages).
- And BTW again, in your document example (MWE: Minimal Working Example) is sufficient to load only `arrows`, `calc` and `positioning` libraries.